# Adding CNAME www fails on godaddy

Tags: cname

I hosted my website on blogger.com. They asked me to add 2 CNAME records; one got added fine on godaddy but other (www) is not getting added. It gives me error "An Unexpected Error Occurred. If This Issue Continues, Contact Support. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that www CNAME is already defined with value as @ . Godaddy was not giving proper error message that "CNAME already exists". I just edited that existing CNAME and it worked fine.